# HTMLDocument object from HTTP read()

Tags: dart

I need to call at server side, an URL and work with the HTML content off the response. For this I'm using the HTTP library from Dart like this :

```
http.read('myUrl').then((contents) {
    //contents to HTMLDocument format //Need to transform the String contents to HTML object
});
```

And I want to convert the response to a HTMLDocument (or other object I don't know) to be able to retrieve element in it by HTML tag or CSS class, like with JQuery for example.

Does anybody have an idea to perform this ?

Answer (score 1):

You canuse **[html5lib](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html5lib)** package from pub. It allows to parse HTML and present it DOM like element tree on server side. The element tree will eventually *"be compatible with dart:html, so the same code will work on the client and the server"* in the future. See the readme for a getting started example.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to call at server side"

Not sure exactly what you mean.

If you are running in the browser and calling the server you could try using a [DocumentFragment](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/be/latest/dart_html/DocumentFragment.html). Something like this:

```
http.read(url).then((html) {
    var fragment = new DocumentFragment(html);
    var element = fragment.query('.foo');
    // code here...
});
```

Otherwise if you're running server side, as the other answer mentions, html5lib is the way to go. Last time I looked the query() method in html5lib only supported tagname queries not classes, or ids.